# ORA-01722: invalid number - not trying to convert strings to numbers

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error?

I had a look at similar questions, but I'm not trying to convert any strings into numbers....

```
select * from SCHEMA.M001100
  WHERE CSX NOT in ('ODZ','TLQ','DES')
  AND ITJ NOT IN (5)
  AND TYN NOT IN (123,456,789);
```

Comment: What is the schema of the table you are querying? Posting the table definition with columns/data types would be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. When I added in inverted commas around the numbers in the AND statements, the query worked, which is surprising, as I believe the data in those columns were numbers rather than strings, which is why I left the quotes out. What's the quickest way to check the character type in a column?

Comment: If ITJ and/or TYN are VARCHAR2 (or similar), then you'll have to enclose those values into single quotes. How to check their datatype? `select * from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'M001100'` (presuming you're connected as SCHEMA user).